# How to expand and fill third dim of black and white image

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have a black and white image with (224,224) shape, but I want to have (224,224,3), so I need to expand the dim, but not with empty value, so `np.expand_dims` or `np.atleast_3d` couldn't help me. How can I do this correctly? Thanks.

What I use:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('data/'+link)
rsize = img.resize((224,224))
rsizeArr = np.asarray(rsize)
```

Comment: What do you want to put in the extra dimension? if you want to suppy evenly spaced `x` and `y` values, then I think `np.meshgrid` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use [**`numpy.dstack()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html), we don't have to expand the dimension manually, it will take care of that work and stack it along the third axis which is what we want.

```
In [4]: grayscale = np.random.random_sample((224,224))

# make it RGB by stacking the grayscale image along depth dimension 3 times
In [5]: rgb = np.dstack([grayscale]*3)

In [6]: rgb.shape
Out[6]: (224, 224, 3)
```

---

For your specific case, it should be:

```
rsize_rgb = np.dstack([rsize]*3)
```

---

For whatever reason, if you still want to *expand the dimension* of your grayscale image by 1 and then make it as RGB image, then you can use [**`numpy.concatenate()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) as in:

```
In [9]: rgb = np.concatenate([grayscale[..., np.newaxis]]*3, axis=2)
In [10]: rgb.shape
Out[10]: (224, 224, 3)
```

For your specific case, it would then be:

```
rsize_rgb = np.concatenate([rsize[..., np.newaxis]]*3, axis=2)
```